# Why primitive View in SwiftUI has no body?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The `View` protocol requires a `body` property:

```swift
public protocol View {
    associatedtype Body : View

    @ViewBuilder var body: Self.Body { get }
}
```

Why have some built-in Views in SwiftUI no body?

```swift
@frozen public struct EmptyView : View {
    @inlinable public init()

    public typealias Body = Never
}
```

```swift
@frozen public struct VStack<Content> : View where Content : View {
    @inlinable public init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)

    public typealias Body = Never
}
```

have no `body` at all..

```swift
let emptyView = EmptyView().body
// Value of type 'EmptyView' has no member 'body'

let vStackView = VStack { Text("some text")}.body
// Value of type 'VStack<Text>' has no member 'body'
```

How are these `View`s implemented?

Comment: Interesting discussion of this in https://cocoawithlove.com/blog/swiftui-natural-pattern.html, under the "construction role" heading

Comment: Seems you've found yet another shady corner of Swift. `func getBody<T: View>(view: T) {
    view.body
}

getBody(view: EmptyView())` even crashes at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each primitive view does have a `body`, but it isn't directly accessible at compile-time. The official Swift forums have [a thread about this topic](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-does-swift-prevent-swiftui-body-never-properties-from-being-called/59253). I'll reproduce my analysis here.

Let's consider `Text`.

A `Text` value has a `body` property, as all `View`s do. `Text`'s `body` calls `fatalError`:

```
import SwiftUI

func body<V: View>(of view: V) -> V.Body { view.body }

body(of: Text("hello"))

// runtime output:

SwiftUI/View.swift:94: Fatal error: body() should not be called on Text.
```

However, if we attempt to access the `body` property directly, the compiler rejects the program:

```
import SwiftUI

Text("hello").body
```

Output:

[image: Xcode showing an error message attached to the use of ‘body’. The error message says “Value of type 'Text' has no member 'body'”.]

The compiler rejects the program because SwiftUI's `swiftinterface` file doesn't declare a body property for `Text`.

Why doesn't `Text`'s declaration include `body`? I don't know for sure because I don't have access to the SwiftUI source code, but I have discovered that we can use [`@_spi`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2f5492f572818e728e3358c13315c2d4e5c9be64/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md#_spispiname) to omit a declaration from a `.swiftinterface` file.

I put the following into `MyView.swift`:

```
import SwiftUI

public struct MyView: View {
    @_spi(Private)
    public var body: Never { fatalError() }
}
```

Then I compile it as follows, based on the “Directly invoking the compiler” instructions found [here](https://www.swift.org/blog/library-evolution/):

```
swiftc MyView.swift -module-name MyLib -emit-module -emit-library -emit-module-interface -enable-library-evolution
```

The compiler writes `MyLib.swiftinterface` as follows, **omitting the `body` declaration**:

```
// swift-interface-format-version: 1.0
// swift-compiler-version: Apple Swift version 5.7 (swiftlang-5.7.0.123.7 clang-1400.0.29.50)
// swift-module-flags: -target arm64-apple-macosx12.0 -enable-objc-interop -enable-library-evolution -module-name MyLib
import Swift
import SwiftUI
import _Concurrency
import _StringProcessing
public struct MyView : SwiftUI.View {
  public typealias Body = Swift.Never
}
```

And it writes `MyLib.private.swiftinterface` as follows, containing the `body` declaration:

```
// swift-interface-format-version: 1.0
// swift-compiler-version: Apple Swift version 5.7 (swiftlang-5.7.0.123.7 clang-1400.0.29.50)
// swift-module-flags: -target arm64-apple-macosx12.0 -enable-objc-interop -enable-library-evolution -module-name MyLib
import Swift
import SwiftUI
import _Concurrency
import _StringProcessing
public struct MyView : SwiftUI.View {
  @_spi(Private) @_Concurrency.MainActor(unsafe) public var body: Swift.Never {
    get
  }
  public typealias Body = Swift.Never
}
```

So my best guess is that SwiftUI applies the `@_spi` attribute to the `body` property of each primitive `View`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but this seems very logical. Imagine that no views are offered by SwiftUI and you want to create the very first view. This view has the computed property `body` that is expecting you to a return a type that conforms to the `View` protocol (i.e. should have the `body` property). This will go forever. Hence, there has to be a View without the `body` property.